# View and sort the results of a Repeater through an index in a column from another table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, repeater

I have two table:

```
TABLE1
+-----------+------+--------+
+ id-table1 + name + childs +
+-----------+------+--------+
+ 1         + one  + 1,3,4  +
+-----------+------+--------+
+ 2         + two  + 3,5,2  +
-----------------------------

TABLE2
+-----------+------+
+ id-table2 + name +
+-----------+------+
+ 1         + one  +
+-----------+------+
+ 2         + two  +
+-----------+------+
+ 3         + three+
+-----------+------+
+ 4         + four +
+-----------+------+
+ 5         + five +
--------------------
```

I need a Repeater (or similar) that displays the records of Table2 that have the "id-table2" contained in the "child" column of Table1 in the same order of "childs" column.

I use SQL and ASP.NET C#.

Thank you to all, excuse my bad english.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ Do you really have a delimited list of children in a single column?

Comment: Hi Sean, thank you. Yes, the children are few and is a simple way to store the sorting together with the list of child. I appreciate suggestions about other ways to do.

Comment: Simple to store but is sucks to use. When you store multiple values in a single cell you violate 1NF and requires you to use a splitter to get them back out. Here is an article that discussed splitters. I would recommend you normalize your data instead but that is up to you. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings For the rest of your question you need to provide some details about the tables and what you expect as output.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to normalize my data and use a more correct method. Thank you Sean!